# Merge Metabots - Automation Anywhere

Tags: rpa, automationanywhere

I have two metabots which i would like to merge for simplicity, is this possible within Automation Anywhere client V11.

For instance I have

Metabot 1 which contains Assets & Logic
Metabot 2 Which Contains Assets & Logic

I would like to have all the asset screens & logic in a single metabot.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid I'll have to disappoint you - there is no way of doing that, certainly not through some intuitive interface.

**DISCLAIMER: I did not try the following and you should make backups of your metabot files before trying yourself.**

You can try modifying the metabot files and see if you can merge them this way. Most of metabot files are zip files containing XML files, or more zip files.

The structure looks a bit like this:

```
Metabot folder
-- .LOGIC files (contains more data, probably not important for this task)
-- content files (.DLL, .SCREEN, ...)
-- [Content_Types].xml (definition of content types)
-- .AAPROJ file (is an XML, not always present, depends on type of metabot)
```

If you are lucky, you could just open Metabot1 archive, copy the .LOGIC and content files from Metabot2 to Metabot1, and ensure that the `[Content_Types].xml` file contains the combined data from both files.

For example, mine looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Types xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">
  <Default Extension="logic" ContentType="text/plain" />
  <Default Extension="aaproj" ContentType="text/plain" />
  <Default Extension="dll" ContentType="text/plain" />
</Types>
```

If you see and AAPROJ file (I see it for some metabots, not for all), you may need to combine them as well (it's an XML as well).

Let's see what happens... but please make sure you keep backups. I would also try it first on metabots build specifically for this test, each with only one or two LOGICs, maybe no content (DLLs or screens) at first.